# Peticion GET con Typescript y React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api, axios

estoy aprendiendo typescript usando react a base de la práctica y sin ver tantos cursos o tutoriales. Un problema que me he encontrado es que a la hora de tener que hacer peticiones tanto con Axios como con Fetch, no entiendo que debería retornar la función o el customHook donde realizo la petición, entiendo que puedo crear un tipo o interfaz con lo que trae la api, pero muchas veces son demasiados datos y debe haber una más simple de poder obtenerlos (sin usar any)

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: En caso de utilizar Axios, para la consulta este devuelve un AxiosResponse.
Y en caso de utilizar fetch es Response. Si utilizas VScode puedes agregar complementos que te ayudan un poco con las sugerencias de las interfaces y types. Saludos